# how can i add a pre-sized (publishing) image to my info path form linked to an issue list in SP2013?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, list, infopath, publishing

i have an info path  form (2013) that linked to an issue list ,how can i add a pre sized (publishing) image  to my info path form? i tried to  add it as column in the site  but not shown in info path!

Answer (score 0):

The "Image with formatting and constraints for publishing" field type is not supported in the InfoPath form. When you customize the SP list form using the InfoPath Designer, you will get the warning message like below.

[image]

In InfoPath form, we can use a *picture control*. This control can be used to display image after you add a picture URL to the control. However, it does not allow user to resize the picture when inserting it.

Comment: exactly, this message shown up .
I also tried with  NINTEX forms , but also not working
It is only working if i created a new list without any modification with Info path.

Comment: It is because the "Image with formatting and constraints for publishing" field type is not supported in the InfoPath form.